# Adding margin 0 to even elements with inserted heading elements

Tags: jquery, css, grid, margin

I'm looking to set margin-right:0 on even elements of the .item divs. However there are headers inserted in places which means the first .item element after a header needs to reset the alternation. This is all dynamic so I can't add a wrapping div to section these.

Example of what I need

```
<h2>heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div> <!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div> <!-- margin-right:0 -->
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
```

What I've tried but doesn't take into consideration the headings:

CSS

```
.item:nth-child(2n) {
     margin-right:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.item:even').css('margin-right', '0');
```

Comment: Not sure why you think adding them dynamically means you can't wrap them properly either at time of generation or once they've loaded.

Comment: What changes, if any, *can* you make to the HTML?  How are the div's generated?  Essentially, this would likely be easier to fix at source.

Comment: @TemanifAfif - why did you remove the 5th .item ?

Comment: @freedomn-m to make the problem not trivial and show that a simpe nth-child(odd) will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is tagged [jquery], you can use `.nextUntil` to find all the `.items` between each `h2` and then filter those to odd/even.

In this case, you need to use `:odd` because they are zero-based (so 1st is row 0 which is even, 2nd is row 1 which is odd, etc)

```js
$("h2").each(function() {
    // have to use :odd for "even" rows as zero-based
    $(this).nextUntil("h2").filter(":odd").addClass("even");
});
```

```css
.wrapper { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
.item { height: 10px; margin-right:20px; border: 1px solid green; }
.item.even { margin-right: 0; background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
<h2>heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div> <!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div> <!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div><!-- margin-right:0 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item:nth-child(odd) {
   margin-right:0 !important;
 }
```

check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5rbyj2ed/6/

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `even` and `odd` keywords in your `nth-child` function :

```
div.item:nth-child(even) {
     margin-right:0;
}
```

You can check this for more details : https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't work as the H2s means that it sometimes needs to skip the next one and reset what is even. See my example.